# $\int_0^{\infty}\frac{\sinh x}{x}\ dx=i\frac{\pi}{2}$. Where is my mistake, or is it correct?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

$$\int_0^{\infty}\frac{\sinh x}{x}\ dx \tag1$$
$$-i\int_0^{\infty}\frac{\sin(ix)}{x}\ dx \tag2$$
$$\text{Substituting}\ t=ix \implies dt=idx$$
$$-i\int_0^{\infty}\frac{\sin t}{-it}(-i)\ dt \tag3$$
$$-i\int_0^{\infty}\frac{\sin t}{t}\ dx=-i\frac{\pi}{2} \tag4$$

Comment: Well, since you are integrating a real valued function, I'm pretty sure you can't end up with an imaginary answer! Looks like you didn't do the substitution right

Comment: i did substitute $t=ix$

Comment: you had one factor of $i$ from your conversion from $\sinh$ to $\sin$, the substitution adds another factor of $i$

Comment: It's like this $-i\int_0^{\infty} \frac{\sin t}{-it}i\ dx$ =$i\int_0^{\infty}\frac{\sin t}{t}\ dt$

Comment: Umm,  $-i \cdot \frac 1 {-i}=1$

Comment: $t=ix$ so $x=-it$ that's why i replaced $x$ with $-it$ in denominator

Comment: The limits : they're no more $0$ to $\infty$, are they?

Comment: you already had a $-i$ outside the integral that cancels with the $-i$ in the denominator you introduced

Comment: After substituting $t=ix$ if $x=0$ then $t=i(0)=0$ i dont know about other one $t=i\infty$

Comment: yes it cancels out but there's another term $idx$ whose $i$ i took outside the integral since it is a constant

Comment: If you plot that function, you'll see it goes off to infinity, so the integral diverges (by comparison with a constant, say). The imaginary substation will just change your limits so you're integrating along the imaginary axis, since the value of the term you put inside the $\sinh$ will always be the same, so the substituted integral along the imaginary axis will also diverge.

Answer (score 3):

As someone pointed out in the comments, it can't be true because you're integrating a real function on a (real) interval : the result cannot be an imaginary value.

It's a problem of notation : after the change of variable, you're integrating $t\mapsto\frac{\sin(t)}{t}$ on the vertical branch $i\mathbb{R}_+^*$, not on the usual horizontal branch $\mathbb{R}_+^*$. There's no reason why the two should be equal. In fact, there's no reason why the first should even exist : try to replicate the proof that the integral $\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\sin(t)}{t}\,dt$ converges on this vertical branch $i\mathbb{R}_+^*$ : it just won't work -- and in fact, it doesn't exist because $x\mapsto\frac{\sinh(x)}{x}$ is not $L^1$ on $\mathbb{R}_+^*$.

Another way to see the problem is to write the change of variable on a finite interval $[a;b]\subset ]0;+\infty[$. With your change of variable, you have $$-i\int_{a}^{b}\frac{\sin(ix)}{x}\,dx=-i\int_{ia}^{ib}\frac{\sin(t)}{t}\,dt$$ There's absolutely no reason why this should be equal to $-i\int_{a}^{b}\frac{\sin(t)}{t}\,dt$.